# Latex new environment pushes environment title to end of page when content is long

Tags: environments, page-breaking

I am trying to figure out why does `\newenvironment` pushes the environment title down to the bottom of the page whenever the environment content is longer than 1 page.
The following is an example. I would like the title in the `longabstract` environment to behave like that of the `shortabstract` (i.e., title and content stay on the same page).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\newenvironment{shortabstract}%
    {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\vfill\begin{center}%
    \bfseries \LARGE Short Abstract \end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
    \setstretch{1.5}
      \begin{shortabstract} 
      \lipsum[1]
       \end{shortabstract}
\newenvironment{longabstract}%
    {\cleardoublepage\null\vfill\begin{center}%
    \bfseries \LARGE Long Abstract\end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
        \begin{longabstract}
      \lipsum[2-5]
       \end{longabstract}
\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Long

Comment: Well the ending \vfill is on the next page, so it can't counteract the starting \vfill.

Comment: You could use a \savebox to test the size of abstract, but you would have to know how much space is left of the page (tricky).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that the `longabstract` is assumed to be more than one page long, so centering it in a page doesn't make sense.

The definitions of the environments should go in the preamble. Avoid commands you don't know about, such as `\null`, and use standard LaTeX commands instead.

Here the short abstract is vertically centered; remove the leading `\vspace*{\fill}` if you want it flush with the top margin.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{shortabstract}
 {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\vspace*{\fill}\begin{center}%
  \bfseries \LARGE Short Abstract\end{center}}%
 {\vspace*{\fill}\cleardoublepage}

\newenvironment{longabstract}
 {\cleardoublepage\begin{center}%
  \bfseries \LARGE Long Abstract\end{center}}%
 {\cleardoublepage}

\setstretch{1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{shortabstract} 
\lipsum[1]
\end{shortabstract}

\begin{longabstract}
\lipsum[2-5]
\end{longabstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @UlrikeFischer comments, I now figure out the answer: Just delete the beginning \vfill in these environments.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\newenvironment{shortabstract}%
    {\cleardoublepage\thispagestyle{empty}\null\begin{center}%
    \bfseries \LARGE Short Abstract \end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
    \setstretch{1.5}
      \begin{shortabstract} 
      \lipsum[1]
       \end{shortabstract}
\newenvironment{longabstract}%
    {\cleardoublepage\null\begin{center}%
    \bfseries \LARGE Long Abstract\end{center}}%
    {\vfill\null}
        \begin{longabstract}
      \lipsum[2-5]
       \end{longabstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tip: mark the code and press the `{}` button to intent all the lines by four spaces to get the formatting above. On a PC you can also mark and press CTRL-k to get the same (not sure if the shortcut is the same on a Mac)